# dynamic column name based on "integer variable"

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, parameters, dynamic-variables

I'm using mssql 2008.

This code is working.

```
declare @colDate1 char(8)
set @colDate1 = 'A'
 EXEC ('SELECT ''value'' AS ' + @colDate1)
```

However, following code has error.

```
declare @colDate1 char(8)
set @colDate1 = '1'
 EXEC ('SELECT ''value'' AS ' + @colDate1)
```

How can I pass parameter consisted of integer to dynamic sql?
Please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an alias like that, you'll need to wrap it in double quotes or square brackets, like so:

```
declare @colDate1 char(8)
set @colDate1 = '1'
 EXEC ('SELECT ''value'' AS [' + @colDate1 + ']')
```

For dynamic aliasing, I'd suggest just always doing it this way, just to be safe.